# How do I try a Live System/Live CD before installing?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

Is it possibly to run it directly from a CD, without installing it completely. I really want to give it a try before installing it definitely.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, although a USB will be faster.**

The following image is of the default start screen of elementary OS Freya 0.3 installer. You can either click the <kbd>Try elementary</kbd> button, or the small <kbd>x</kbd> in the top left-hand corner of the window (they both have the same effect).

[image: elementary OS Installer]